# Unable to delete asset from VersionOne

Tags: delphi

I am trying to delete Backlog item from VersionOne using API but it is not deleting the Backlog in VersionOne. 
I have fired following in POST with empty payload:

'https://wwwXX.v1host.com/XXXX/Account.mvc/LogIn/rest-1.v1/Data/Backlog/1651?op=Delete'

But after this I get following response text as error:

Not FoundUnknown AssetType: Backlog

What shall I do to delete backlog item in VersionOne using API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see "Backlog" on the [list of asset types](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Concepts/Asset_Type). Maybe the error message means exactly what it says. Have you [queried the meta API](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Concepts/Endpoints/meta.v1) to get the list of assets like [the documentation suggests](https://community.versionone.com/Help-Center/Common-Questions/Getting_Started_with_the_API)?

Comment: Yes, I have referred that list of asset type, but my concern is for Backlog record type in VersionOne. When I am fetching / creating / updating records in VersionOne, I am using UI Name for Backlog item i.e. Backlog.

But when I am trying to delete records with same UI name for VersionOne record type, I am getting above error.

Is it not possible to delete the VersionOne records using its UI name in Delete request?

Comment: Please post some code demonstrating a request that works, along with the corresponding code that *doesn't* work. I fear you've confused a *backlog item* with an entire *backlog*. The former has a system name of *Story*, whereas the latter term isn't used in the documentation at all. Posting your code will help clarify what you're really doing.

Comment: And if you don't want to distinguish between Stories and Defects, `PrimaryWorkitem` will work for both.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Rob. I am now able to delete records from VersionOne. I was trying to delete it using the UI name for Story i.e. Backlog.